# JS recursive multiply function without operators

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to create a `multiply` function that takes two number as arguments
and returns the result of the multiplication of those two without using the   operators * or / and no loops. 
when I do this I get the Maximum call stack size exceeded  error

```
    function multiply(x,y){
       let positif = x + multiply(x, (y-1))
       **let negatif = x + multiply(x,(y+1))** this is not working
       if(x<y) return multiply(y,x)
       if((x>0) && (y>=1)){
           return positif
       }if (x>0 || y<= -1){
           return negatif 
    }
   }
```

Comment: Okay, and what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Please give some more information. So far it sounds like we should solve your homework.

Comment: should it work for (positive) integers only? what about logarithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site https://medium.com/@ctrlalt_diljeet/multiply-without-using-in-javascript-890857bb003c gives a good example of doing this. You could expand this by checking whether the inputs are negative to handle numbers with an expected result less than 0

```
function multiply(a, b){
    return ("i").repeat(a).repeat(b).length    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For (positive) integer values, you could use an [Ancient Egyptian multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication) by adding odd values by using a bit shifting.

> ```
>  a   b   sum  comment
> --  --  ----  -----------------
>  5   7     7  add b if a is odd
>  2  14     7
>  1  28    35  add b if a is odd
>  0  56    35  result
>  ^----------- exit condition
> ```

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
    if (!a) { return 0; }
    return a & 1
        ? b + multiply(a >> 1, b << 1)
        : multiply(a >> 1, b << 1);
}

console.log(multiply(5, 7));
```